# Why cannot use `decltype()` for `std::function<>` with lambda?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda

we know that `decltype()` could be used to get type of variables, just like following:

```
int a = 0;
using a_t = decltype(a);
a_t b = -1; // it worked, and type of b is int
```

but it didn't work for this:

```
auto f = [](int a) -> int { return a + 1;}; // the type of callable should be int(int)?

std::function<decltype(f)> F(f); // error
std::function<int(int)> G(f);    // worked
```

why? and is there any method to get function type(in the `<>`) of lambda expression?

Comment: missing `;` after `a+1` and please include the error message in the question

Comment: the type of lambda expression is not **function type**, which is required by `std::function`.

Comment: to deduce the function type of a lambda expression, you can use `decltype(lambda::operator())`, except it's a generic lambda expression.

Comment: With c++17 or later you can do `std::function F(f);` thanks to [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simply improper usage of the `std::function` wrapper. This type is meant to *hide* the actual implementation by wrapping it into a type-erased object with as little information about the underlying callable as possible: and this is the function signature.

When you use `decltype(f)`, you get the acutal unique, compiler-generated type of the lambda expression. But this is not how you can instantiate a `std::function`, as the basic, non-specialized template `template<class> std::function` is undefined. Only the specialization `template<class R, class ...Args> std::function<R(Args...)>` is defined, and you cannot instantiate this with the type of a lambda expression.

Do note that all lambda expression have a signature, too: they accept some arguments (possibly template parameter types) and return a value of some type. Those is the information you need to put into the `std::function` instantiation. In your case `int(int)` as you posted yourself.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any method to get function type (in the `<>`) of lambda expression?

Yes, for capture-less non-generic lambdas there is a user-defined conversion function to get the equivalent function pointer type. Here's how you can use that:

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>

auto f = [](int a) -> int { return a + 1;};

template <class F>
using fn_type_t = std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(+std::declval<F>())>;

std::function<fn_type_t<decltype(f)>> F(f);
```

[Godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/eabc56b8d)

The unary `+` operator triggers the conversion to `int(*)(int)`, and then `std::remove_pointer` obtains `int(int)` from the type of that expression.